# Is there a web script for clients to pick the photos they want to buy from me?

Tags: software, web, selling, event

I'm currently developing a website for a multimedia business and they do event photography. I'm looking for a script/software that could help their clients to pick the photos they want to buy from a specific event.

The idea is to integrate such system on their website and the whole thing should work more or less like this:

They create an event and upload a bunch of photos to that specific event. The photos should be in thumbnails only (for obvious reasons) so if the script has an option to resize all the photos, better. But my opinion is that it's just better if they upload the thumbnails themselves (faster and easier). So resize is not that important. Each event should be password protected so that person A from event X can't access event Y and order photos from an event he/she didn't attend.

After login, the client picks the photos they want (something intuitive like clicking on each photo would be nice), add their name, address, etc, whatever my client wants. And then either e-mail all this information to a specific e-mail address or save them so that my client can login to the admin area and see their clients orders. The payment doesn't need to be in digital fashion.

It doesn't need to work exactly like I described, it's just a basic layout of what my client wants/needs.

Now, I could code all this myself, that's what I do. But unfortunately I don't have time to do it at the moment and it's something we didn't agree to do initially (they never mentioned it to me when we first talked about their website), so I'm not obliged to do it. I don't mind looking for a script, install it and configure it without any extra cost. But developing something like this takes time and would cost them more. But like I said, I have no time for now. The problem is that I can't find anything that does this... Maybe I'm missing the right keyword in searching but English is not my main language and I don't know what else to search for.

Does anyone know of a script that could help me with this. The website is in WordPress so a PHP script is the optimal choice.

Comment: Hello, welcome to the forum. Since this question relates to programming more than photography, I'd ask it on http://stackoverflow.com instead, where you're more likely to get a useful answer. One of the moderators here can migrate it for you.

Comment: Any reason you don't use a service like Smugmug? Check my profile if you want a coupon as well.

Comment: Just looked at Smugmug. It's not what we are looking for and it's a paid service, out of the question.

Comment: This question has been closed but I found exactly what I was looking for as I need this again and never found the perfect solution before. Here it is: http://www.photographyorders.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right: what you're looking for doesn't exist. Not exactly. You need an online service or web software that does all that. smugmug.com is one of the best options. Users can create galleries (and password protect them), which can be sent to their clients. From there, clients can order from hundreds of options of prints and merchandise.

Comment: Smugmug is not exactly what we are looking for. And it's a paid subscription service so it's out of the question. I'll mark this answer as accepted if nothing else better comes up.

Comment: You're asking for an all-in-one solution that not only displays images, but also works as a cart (sort of), and has a log in area. I'm not sure how familiar you are with scripting, but that's a pretty (very pretty) tall order for just a free cut-and-paste script.

Comment: I'm a web-developer so I'm very familiar with scripting and that's why I don't agree with your statement. There are scrits/applications out there, that are way more complex than the script I'm looking for, for free. I have the skills to develop what I need, I just don't have the time for it right now. That's the reason I'm looking for something already made.